# SSLError Unexpected EOF - Python 2.7

Tags: python, ssl

SSLError Unexpected EOF - py 2.7 Intermittent issue

```
line 76, in use_ap_to_fire#012    self.dummy.url, json=payload, 
timeout=self.timeout#012  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 559, in post#012    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, 
json=json, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 512, in request#012    resp = self.send(prep, 
**send_kwargs)#012  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/raven/breadcrumbs.py", 
line 341, in send#012    resp = real_send(self, request, *args, 
**kwargs)#012  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/requests/sessions.py", 
line 622, in send#012    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)#012  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", 
line 511, in send#012    raise SSLError(e, 
request=request)#012SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somedns', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /test (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected 
EOF')",),))
```

I am seeing the above exception once in a while hitting a service using py 2.7. I am new to python as well as ssl. I am clueless on how to investigate this issue.

Comment: The error isn't within ssl or python, the error is whatever causing the server to retry so many times until server would end request like that: `Max retries exceeded with url: /test`

Comment: But the max retries are caused by SSLError.